# Prime subring of a field with char $p$ or $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field. If char$(F) = p>0$, show that the prime subring of $F$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, and if char$(F) = 0$, then the prime subring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have shown that if char$(F) = p>0$ then $p$ is prime. Now, I tried to build a homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{F}_{p} \longrightarrow P$ but I couldn't conclude the bijective. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: What do you mean by "_the prime subring_" of $F$? Since $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$, there exists $1$ in $F$ and $\langle 1\rangle$ is a subring of $F$ of order $p$ and is clearly a prime ring. Are you referring to this prime subring?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I think the customary definition is "the intersection of all unital subrings of $F$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural map $\pi:\mathbb Z\to F$ given by $1\mapsto 1_F$ and extended additively is automatically onto the prime subring of $F$ in any case. If this is your difficulty, then maybe I can spend more time talking about it. Just ask.

Then the first homomrphism theorem says that $\mathbb Z/\ker(\pi)$ is isomorphic to its image, the prime subring.

Since the image is a domain, $\ker(\pi)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$, and we know what the options are for those.

Comment: I understood almost the whole idea. If possible, I would like a little more explanation about "is automatically onto the prime subring of F in any case"

Comment: @LucasCorrêa, Recall that $\langle 1_F\rangle=F$, so since $\pi$ is extended additively, we have $\operatorname{im}\pi=F$ which makes $\pi$ surjective.